# hide extension of the page like .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a path say **"http://default.com/index.aspx"** here i can see page **"index.aspx"** page content but I donot want to show ".aspx" extension on my browser url.
I can do this while making a folder name as "index" and putting my index.aspx page in that folder and just making write url as **"http://default.com/index/"**

But is there another simple and good way to do soo?.I am using asp.net 4.0

Comment: You could google for "URL rewriting".

Comment: Just a question, why not use MVC which does this out of the box already?

Comment: @user65439 i have no knowledge of MVC soo.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using asp.net 4.0, then you can use the NuGet Package Manager to add the 'Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls' library. It look like this:[image]

Install the first one (will also install the next one automaticlly). After the install completed, it add a cs file name 'RouteConfig.cs' under the App_Start folder; the file's code like below:

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    }
}
```

To enable the friendly url , you need to add the below code to the global.asax

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj891072(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you google for *URL rewriting* there should be many results that show you how to turn `http://default.com/index.aspx?value=13` into `http://default.com/index/13`.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [UrlRwrting.net](http://www.urlrewriting.net/) for years, works good.

With that DDL, all you need to add in your webconfig is something like this:

```
<urlrewritingnet defaultProvider="RegEx" xmlns="http://www.urlrewriting.net/schemas/config/2006/07">
  <rewrites>
    <add name="rule1" virtualUrl="^~/(.*)/" destinationUrl="~/$1.aspx" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <add name="rule2" virtualUrl="^~/(.*)" destinationUrl="~/$1.aspx" ignoreCase="true"/>
  </rewrites>
</urlrewritingnet>
```